# How to select rows from a table with identical but random values in a column without knowing that value with only one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Let's assume the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_abc` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `val_abc` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO test_abc (val_abc) VALUES
(1), (2), (1), (1), (3), (2), (3), (2), (3), (3), (3);

id | val_abc
------------
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 1
4  | 1
5  | 3
6  | 2
7  | 3
8  | 2
9  | 3
10 | 3
11 | 3
```

Now I want to select all rows with the same `val_abc`, while it doesn't matter which `val_abc` it is - but since it shouldn't be always the same one, there needs to be a random factor. So basically randomly either all rows with `val_abc = 1` or all rows with `val_abc = 2` and so on. The values of val_abc can be anything (even non numeric) and are unknown at the code level. Expected results would be, for example:

```
id | val_abc
------------
2  | 2
6  | 2
8  | 2

id | val_abc
------------
5  | 3
7  | 3
9  | 3
10 | 3
11 | 3
```

I could, of course, make 2 queries. One to get a random but existing value of `val_abc`, for example `SELECT val_abc FROM test_abc ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`. And then a second query to get all rows with this specific value in `val_abc`.

A second possibility would be to use a sub query, like `SELECT * FROM test_abc WHERE val_abc = (SELECT val_abc FROM test_abc ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)`. But this actually doesn't work (MariaDB 5). The results seem to be totally random and different every time (1 row, 5 rows, 3 rows, mixed val_abc values and so on), what I don't fully understand yet. It looks like the combination of ORDER BY RAND and LIMIT won't work in a sub query as expected.

Is there any possibility to achieve this with a sub select or even with a query without any sub queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the comparison to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test_abc t JOIN
    (SELECT val_abc FROM test_abc ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) trand
     ON t.val_abc = trand.val_abc;
```

The subquery in the `FROM` clause is evaluated only one time, so you will get only one row.  In the `WHERE` clause, the subquery is evaluated once for each row, so you get a different value each time.

Comment: Ok, I see. Now I understand the weird results I've gotten with the sub query.